# Error loading polygon geometries using shape file data store with geotools 24.0

Tags: polygon, geotools

I have recently upgraded my geotools dependencies from 23.2 to 24.0
i have the following error when i try to load a `FeatureCollection` from a shape file data store with a polygon geometry,seems this problem was introduced in 24.0 geotools release ,anyone now how to solve this problem please

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon.getExteriorRing()Lorg/locationtech/jts/geom/LineString;
```

Comment: That looks like you haven't upgraded your JTS dependency - can you add the dependencies from your pom file

Comment: I just fix the probleme by adding the jts 1.16.1 dependency to my gradle project compile group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.16.1' i think the solution is to downgrade the jts version as it does not work with geolatte in recent versions.

Comment: I think the issue was with  the Incompatibility between geolatte-geom 1.6.0 and jts-core 1.17.0,i recently read un article about that : https://gitmemory.com/issue/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom/111/655654867,the cause is that The cause is that in version 1.17.0 of JTS the class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon returns a LinearRing instead of a LineString in the method getExteriorRing.

Comment: Exactly, so you can't run GeoTools 24.x until GeoLatte upgrades it version of JTS

Comment: But i am running now geotools 24.0 with jts 1.16.1 it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoTools upgraded to version 1.17.0 of JTS with version 24.0 - this [changed the return type of the `getExteriorRing` to `LinearRing` from `LineString`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/releases). This is supposed to be only a binary change so you should be able to handle it by just recompiling the code that uses that method.